# Why wouldn't make not execute a simple line in the makefile

Tags: makefile

This is my first time using make, and i've been spinning my wheels trying to get past an issue.  I can't understand why a simple echo never gets executed:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall 
LDFLAGS = -g
CC = gcc
SRCS = p4a.c p4b.c

p4static:   p4a.c
    gcc $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $< -static -L. -lpthread


p4dynlink:  p4a.c
    @echo "this doesn't print/echo/execute"
    gcc $(LDFLAGS) -o p4dynlink $< -L. -lpthread
```

I'm using tab instead of spaces.  Here is the outputs:

```
mike@elementary:~/p4$ make
gcc -g -o p4static p4a.c -static -L. -lpthread
mike@elementary:~/p4$ make
make: `p4static' is up to date.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How `make` Processes a Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#How-Make-Works):

> By default, make starts with the first target (not targets whose names start with ‘.’). This is called the default goal. [....]
>
> Thus, when you give the command:
>
> ```
> make
> ```
>
> make reads the makefile in the current directory and begins by processing the first rule.

So when you type `make` make tries to build your `p4static` target which doesn't have an `echo` line. And the next time you run `make` it says that target is up to date and has nothing to do.

To build `p4dynlink` you need to tell make to build that target `make p4dynlink`.

You can set the default goal manually (in the makefile) with [`.DEFAULT_GOAL`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002eDEFAULT_005fGOAL-_0028define-default-goal_0029):

> ```
> # Set our own.
> .DEFAULT_GOAL := foo
> ```

But convention is usually to create an `all` target as the first target and have it "Do the Right Thing" by default.

So in your case, assuming you wanted both targets built by default, you would use:

```
all: p4static p4dynlink
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!  I had no idea!
I've been looking in that docuement thinking the rule was wrong.